# Whats Wrong with this code it generate the error divide by zero

Tags: php, laravel

I am calculating star rating but my code is not working and generate the divide by zero. if i use static value instead of $no_of_ratings it works

```
<?php
    $value = array("1"=>NULL,"2"=>NULL,"3"=>NULL,"4"=>NULL,"5"=>NULL);
    $no_of_ratings = 0;
?>

@foreach($workshop->ratings as $ratings)
    <?php $no_of_ratings ++ ?>
    @if($ratings->ratings == 5)
        <?php  $value[5] += $ratings->ratings ?>
    @elseif($ratings->ratings == 4) 
        <?php $value[4] += $ratings->ratings ?>
    @elseif($ratings->ratings == 3) 
        <?php $value[3] += $ratings->ratings ?>
    @elseif($ratings->ratings == 2) 
        <?php $value[2] += $ratings->ratings ?>
    @elseif($ratings->ratings == 1)
        <?php $value[1] += $ratings->ratings ?>
    @endif  
@endforeach

<?php 
    $no_of_ratings; 

    $final_value = (integer)($value[5] + $value[4] + $value[3] +$value[2] + $value[1] );

    echo $rating = ceil($final_value/$no_of_ratings);

?>
```

Comment: Just before you do the division you declare `$no_of_ratings;` but assign no value... Initially it is set at zero and never changes until the end

Comment: Wouldn't `$value[$ratings->ratings] += $ratings->ratings` simplify the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you modify the loop to include the index

```
@foreach($workshop->ratings as $i => $ratings)
```

Then assign that counter as the value to `$no_of_ratings` at the end of the loop

```
$no_of_ratings=$i;
```

When the division now occurs there at least should be a value greater than zero. There are other ways you could do that - use the `count` or `sizeof` to find length of the `$workshop->ratings` variable

Comment: Would still be zero if there are no ratings (`$workshop->ratings` is an empty array).

Comment: very true... wrap the whole lot in an `if( !empty($workshop->ratings) )` type clause

Comment: Thanks All I have made it